# Examples of Proper Orthogonal Factorization Systems

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

A *proper* orthogonal factorization system $(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{M})$ is an orthogonal factorization system where every $f \in \mathcal{E}$ is an epimorphism and every $f \in \mathcal{M}$ is a monomorphism.

I'm interested in examples on bicomplete categories other than the obvious (epimorphism, strong monomorphism) and (strong epimorphism, monomorphism) ones (which both exist when the category is well-powered and well-copowered). An example on topological spaces or k-spaces would be ideal.

Comment: A silly example: suppose you have a category $\mathcal{C}$ with both (epi, strong mono) and (strong epi, mono) OFSes; then on $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ you have an OFS that is (epi, strong mono) on one component and (strong epi, mono) on the other, right?

Comment: Good point. I should have remembered this example. I'm still very interested in seeing an example for Top though.